# What is the most light weight lightbox jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

I have been looking around, but I was wondering whats the most light weight lightbox plugin.  One that does not really lag when it opens, animation is present, but minimal.  I need one that can handle inline divs as well as ajax calls.  Is it simply better to make your own? Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

This is the one that I've found works best across all browsers and is nice and snappy:

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/

Answer (score 0):

My experience in these situations has shown it is best to write or customize your own. That said, download one of the suggested plugins and then open it up and cut out the options you don't need. You might find yourself with 5 lines of code that you could have written yourself.